# How to capture audio streaming with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-streaming

I'd like to capture audio streaming from a live radio on internet using ffmpeg.

If you have some examples or documentation it will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the protocol is HTTP and audio format is MP3 it can be as simple as:

```
ffmpeg -i http://server:port -c copy output.mp3
```

See:

- [FFmpeg Protocols Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html)
- [`ffmpeg` Documentation: Stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy)